# intento guardar el valor de un select en un input y me sale el siguiente error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'o' of undefined

Tags: javascript

aqui esta mi codigo:

```
<?php
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/LinqSy/Emisiones/clase.php');
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/LinqSy/debug/ChromePhp.php'; 
$view2= new stdClass();
$view2->disableLayout=true;
$view2->acreedores=Fideicomiso::getGrupos($_POST[menu]);
if (isset($_POST[acred])) {
        $editId=intval($_POST[acred]);
        //vista para los datos generales
        $view2->fideV=new Fideicomiso($editId);
    }
?>

<form name ="ac" id="ac" >
  <!-- <input type="text" name="menu" id="menu" value = "<?php print $view->fideV->getID()?>"> -->
  <input type="text" name="o" id="o" value = "" >
  <div>
        <br><label>Grupo de Acreedores</label>
        <select  class="acree"; name="acree" id="acree">
                <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
                <?php foreach ($view2->acreedores as $acreedores){?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $acreedores['Grupo'];?>"><?php echo $acreedores['Grupo']; ?></option>
            <?php }?></h3>          
        </select>  
  </div>  
</form>

</body>

 <script>

    $('#acree').change('click',function(){

            // Así accedemos al Valor de la opción seleccionada
             document.ac.o.value=$("#acree option:selected").val();
             params={};
             params.relacion= $("#acree option:selected").val();
             alert(params.relacion);

             if(params.relacion!=null){
                     $("#conceptos").html('<div><img src="upload.gif"/></div>');
                 $("#conceptos").load("RExpedientes/conceptos/vistac.php",params, function(response, status, xhr){
                            if (status == "error") {
                              var msg = "Error!, algo ha sucedido: ";
                              $("#capa").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                            }
                          });
                  }
     });
</script>
```

dice que mi input no esta definido, ya no encuentro mas para hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque el objeto ac no existe dentro de document, podrias hacerlo así:

```
document.getElementById('o').value = $("#acree option:selected").val();
```

O podrías utilizar solo JQuery:

```
$('#o').value($("#acree option:selected").val())
```

Como buena práctica es mejor que utilices nombres más descriptivos para los ids de tus inputs.

Answer (score 0):

ok lo que tu estas haciendo es

```
document.ac.o.value=$("#acree option:selected").val();
```

pero así no se navega a través del `DOM Document`, lo ideal es obtener los `HTML Objects` a través de los métodos que tiene esta colección como por ejemplo:

```
getElementById()    
getElementsByClassName()    
getElementsByName() 
getElementsByTagName()
```

ahora si quieres acceder directamente por la `id`lo que puedes hacer es:

```
document.all.o
```

pero no te lo recomiendo, es mejor usar los métodos que esta colección tiene, te dejo un link con la lista de métodos para que los veas.

[DOM Document](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

**PD:** si ya estas usando jQuery no le veo mucho sentido usar la nomenclatura de javascript nativa a menos que quieras mejorar rendimiento de tu sitio web

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, ya corregí mi codigo, el problema, aparentemente, era que no cargaba jquery en mi formulario, pero ya quedo.